# Reading a file and creating a user in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a list of IP address along with me. In front of those IP I have a username. What I am trying to do is make Chef read the file having IP and username and once it encounter the IP, it should create a user of that name.
But when I do I get a user but the name of the user comes out to be a number.

Here is my recipe

```
File.open("/tmp/users.txt", "r") do |file|
    file.readlines.each_with_index do |ip,user|
      if ip = node[:ipaddress]
            user ip[user] do
                action :create
                supports :manage_home => true
                comment 'Test User'
                home '/home/ip[user]'
                shell '/bin/bash'
                password 'password'
            end
      end
   end
```

my users.txt file

```
231.27.59.232, test1
272.27.59.15, tes2
985.54.25.22, test3
```

Now when I run the recipe this is what I get

```
Recipe: repo_update::users
   * cookbook_file[/tmp/users.txt] action create (up to date)
   * user[1] action create
     - create user 1
   * user[7] action create
     - create user 7
   * user[2] action create
     - create user 2
```

Please tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: I suggest the "users" cookbook. Lot simpler to just load your user data into a databag and let chef do its stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problem here... The answer of Tejay is the way to go, I'll just try to explain why your code don't work and how to fix it so it could be of some use later :)

```
File.open("/tmp/users.txt", "r") do |file|
  file.readlines.each_with_index do |ip,user|
    puts "values are #{ip} and #{user}"
  end
end
```

Gives:

```
values are 231.27.59.232, test1
 and 0
values are 272.27.59.15, tes2
 and 1
values are 985.54.25.22, test3
 and 2
```

`each_with_index` won't split magically your line into two part, it will just assign the last parameter the actual index in the iteration.

A fixed version of your code would be:

```
File.open("/tmp/users.txt", "r") do |file|
  file.readlines.each do |line| # just iterate and get line
    ip,myuser=line.gsub("\n",'').split(',') # set ip and myuser variable with values comma separated, using myuser to avoid conflict with the resource name. Using gsub to remove traling carriage return in user name
    if ip == node[:ipaddress] # test equality, a single = will assign ip a value and always be true.
      user myuser do # create the user using the variable, no need to interpolate here
        action :create
        supports :manage_home => true
        comment 'Test User'
        home "/home/#{myuser}" # use interpolation here inside double quotes (won't work in single quotes)
        shell '/bin/bash'
        password 'password'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tensibai, you explanation is awesome. Thanks. Just one issue, when i try to run our code, the username of a user is taken with a '\n'. Because of this the user which is getting created becomes "test1
"
Now to solve this i changed the users.txt file by applying a '/' in front of the username, but i didnt help. Can u provide a solution for this

Comment: @Ismail you'll have to suppress the \n indeed. Editing for this

Comment: I even tried using  ip,myuser=line.split(',').rstrip('\n'), but it is also not working

Comment: @Ismail `ip,myuser=line.gsub("\n",'').split(',')` this should work

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks a lot, can u please explain what actually u did. I mean why to use empty quotes after \n..?

Comment: `gsub(<pattern>,<replacement>)` Here I want carrage returns to be repalced by nothing. A rstrip would do to, just that I'm used to .gsub

Comment: I tried with rsprit, but it always gives the same error, that is wrong number of arguements. But yes with gsub it went smooth. Thanks.
Just last help can you tell me a link for a good example for databags of chef.(if possible, although the goal is acheived). :)

Comment: @Ismail best idea: http://docs.chef.io as the subject is quite vast, I've no great link over it right now. You may have a look at the [user cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/users) which use databags. with correct link this time :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
user ip[user] do
```

You are calling the `[]` method on the `ip` string.  Furthermore, you're going to get a name collision between the resource `user` and the block variable. Finally, you are giving each user the home of '/home/ip[user]'.  You need to put the string in `"`'s and wrap the variable in `#{` and `}` Try this:

```
File.open("/tmp/users.txt", "r") do |file|
  file.readlines.each do |line|
    entries = line.split(',')
    ip = entries[0].strip
    username = entries[1].strip
    if ip = node[:ipaddress]
      user username do
        action :create
        supports :manage_home => true
        comment 'Test User'
        home "/home/#{username}"
        shell '/bin/bash'
        password 'password'
      end
    end
 end
```

Also, reading this all from a file is a very non cheffy thing to do. Either use a databag or a hash stored in an environment variable, which also saves you from needing to loop at all:

```
userhash = node['my_users'][node['ipadddress']]
user userhash['username']
  action :create
  supports :manage_home => true
  comment 'test user'
  home userhash['home'] || "/home/#{userhash['username']"
  shell userhash['shell'] || '/bin/bash'
  password userhash['password'] || 'password'
end
```

Comment: Hi Tejay, thanks for explaining. When i tried your code it gives an error    ERROR: user[0] (repo_update::users line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option username must be a kind of [String]!  You passed 0.

although i would like to know what you mean by using databags. I tried it beginning but was unable to understand much of the databags things and how they are created. May be you can help on that. Thanks

Comment: Wow, sorry.  I just realized what you were doing with the `each_with_index`.  I'll update the answer to work, but I'd still strongly suggest using a hash, rather than a file.  I wish I could help with the databags, but I can't really offer much more than what's in the documentation.  You can look at the `users` cookbook on the supermarket.

Comment: Thanks. Tejay. Yeah even tensibai suggested me to look at the cookbook. Will look into it